# Need Help C# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object, reference, instance

Can you help me solve following **Error Message**:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I marked the areas I get the error with comments and `**`

Please see below.

```
private static void _GenerateWord(string fname, string reportStartDate, string reportEndDate)
        { 
            var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            word.Visible = false;
            object missing = Type.Missing;

            object fileName = (@LetterTemplateLocation + LetterName);

            doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName);


            doc.Activate();//**Error message here "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

            string dateWithFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");

            //**Error message here "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tmpRange in doc.StoryRanges)
            {
                _FindAndReplace("<date>", dateWithFormat, tmpRange, missing);

                _FindAndReplace("<filename>", fname, tmpRange, missing);

                _FindAndReplace("<startdate>", reportStartDate, tmpRange, missing);

                _FindAndReplace("<enddate>", reportEndDate, tmpRange, missing);
            }

            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                word.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like `doc` get's null. Are your sure `fileName` is a path to an existing word document file?

Comment: I would check if fileName exist first.. bool found = File.Exist(fileName)

Comment: @Idan Arye: Yes, `fileName` is a path to an existing word template. thanks!

Comment: Why is your fileName typed as object?  .Documents.Open takes a string parameter.

Comment: fileName is taking object only. If I change to string I get invalid argument error.

Comment: Also, I am not sure why people voted I didn't research before I posted the question. I researched for hours didn't find/understand any solution that can help. Maybe some people are more experience in finding the answers because those people knows what to look for. I am here because I am a noob trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

As a practice need to check doc for null.

> If(doc !=null){...}

Also need to evaluate valid file, as others suggested.